# Outrageously Slow File Copying From Windows 10 Host to Ubuntu 19.04 VM

Tags: networking, mount, windows, samba, hyper-v

I am trying to copy files from an SMB share on the Windows machine that is running my Ubuntu VM in Hyper-V. The VM has 16gb memory and 2 CPU. It's set up with a virtual switch to have its own separate vNIC and IP address. I can access my shares just fine, even write to them at normal speeds so far as I've tested. I can even read from the share at a decent speed (though less than what it should be). However, when I copy a 690mb folder with 692 files from the Windows share to the Documents folder in my Home dir on Ubuntu, it gives me a 24 hour estimated time to copy all files.

The share is mounted using the following command:

`mount -t cifs username=myusername,uid=1000,gid=1000 smb://IPADDRESS/SHARENAME ./foldername`

EDIT/UPDATE: I discovered that the copy of these files is really fast if I use the cp command from the terminal, but if I use the Ubuntu desktop GUI to copy/paste or drag/drop the folder, that is when it actually takes ages.

What is going on here?